# C++ Pointers and Dynamic Arrays and Delete Operator

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-arrays, delete-operator

Ok so I am going to lay out two programs.  Both are dynamic arrays using pointers and the new operator.  But one doesn't seem to like the delete operator.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  int *p;
  p = new int[5];

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    p[i] = 25 + (i * 10);
    std::cout << p[i] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  delete [] p;
  p = NULL;

  return 0;
}
```

That's the first program.  It likes the delete operator just fine.  Now the program that dislikes the delete operator:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  int x;
  int *p;
  p = new int[5];

  *p = 4;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    std::cout << *p << " ";
    x = *p;
    p++;
    *p = x + 1;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  delete [] p;
  p = NULL;

  return 0;
}
```

This program compiles just fine.  But during execution, it throws an error - `free(): invalid pointer: 0xfdb038` .. or whatever the memory address is for that particular execution. So, the question is: 
Why can't the delete operator be used in the second case?
I don't want to have memory leak; I don't want the pointer to be dangling.
If I just say `p = NULL;`, then `p = 0`, but I believe the pointer is still dangling?, but I'm not sure.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because in the second case you change the `p` pointer and it doesn't point to the array beginning before the deleting.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this loop in the second piece of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  std::cout << *p << " ";
  x = *p;
  p++;
  *p = x + 1;   // <--- Here
}
```

Notice that in this line, you write to the memory address currently pointed at by `p`. Since you always increment `p` and then write to it, you end up writing off past the end of the region that you allocated for `p`. (If we imagine `pOrig` as a pointer to where `p` initially points, then this writes to `pOrig[1]`, `pOrig[2]`, `pOrig[3]`, `pOrig[4]`, and `pOrig[5]`, and that last write is past the end of the region). This results in undefined behavior, meaning that literally anything can happen. This is Bad News.

Additionally, `delete[]` assumes that you are passing in a pointer to the very first element of the array that you allocated. Since you've incremented `p` so many times in that loop, you're trying to `delete[]` a pointer that wasn't at the base of the allocated array, hence the issue.

To fix this, don't write to `p` after incrementing it, and store a pointer to the original array allocated with `new[]` so that you can free that rather than the modified pointer `p`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `delete` the pointer that you got from `new`. However, in your second code you did `p++` which changed the pointer. Therefore you tried to `delete` a pointer you didn't get from `new` and `delete` crashes.

To fix this type of error never use `new`. Instead use `std::vector<int> p;`. Since you never need `new` you cannot forget a `delete`.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan How is that strange? You will notice that you will not find manual memory management in modern C++. There is no need to subject yourself to this error-prone, outdated and unnecessary practice.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan There actually is a trend in modern C++ to avoid explicit `new` and `delete` operators. Look at, for example, `make_shared` and `make_unique` in conjunction with smart pointer types.

Comment: @templatetypedef I mean that you can't avoid using explicitly new/delete because of many C libraries, for example, which deal with arrays and raw pointers. So it's much more better to learn how to use new/delete appropriately instead of ignoring them. In such context the phrase "never use new" looks strange for me. Besides the aforementioned advice doesn't answer the question directly.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan C doesn't use `new` or `delete`, therefore you never *need* `new` or `delete` to work with C libraries.  You just use a `std::vector` and pass pointers to the data to the C library.
The first paragraph answers the question directly, the second in a general manner, I don't see how it doesn't.

Comment: @templatetypedef What if C library needs a preallocated buffer to fill in? Do you claim that it's better to create a vector and use pointers to it's buffer instead of simply using new and delete?

Comment: @EdgarRokyan Sorry, to clarify - I'm not saying that there are *no* uses for `new` and `delete` as much as that there's been a shift toward avoiding them. And also, yes, it probably would be a better idea to use the `std::vector` - it's exception-safe and it's easier to use it correctly than incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is changing `p` in `p++`.
You should always store (to delete) original pointer. Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  int *original = new int[5];
  int *p = original;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    std::cout << *p << " ";
    int x = *p;
    p++;
    *p = x + 1;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  delete [] original;    
  return 0;
}
```